# Immuconf with Clojure not handling tree config files

Tags: clojure

Whenever I add a third config file to my `.immuconf.edn` I get:

```
   No configuration files were specified, and neither an .immuconf.edn file nor
   an IMMUCONF_CFG environment variable was found
```

This is driving me crazy since I cant really find anything wrong.

Using this loads thing OK:

```
["configs/betfair.edn" "configs/web-server.edn"]
```

however this generated an error:

```
["configs/betfair.edn" "configs/web-server.edn" "~/betfair.edn"]
```

This is the content of `betfair.edn`

```
{:betfair {:usr "..."
           :pwd "..."
           :app-key "..." ;; key used
           :app-key-live "..."
           :app-key-test "..."}}
```

(where ... is replaced with actual strings)

Why am I getting this error when adding the third file and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the last file specified in your `<project dir>/.immuconf.edn` (`~/betfair.edn`) exists in your home directory.

Immuconf does [some magic](https://github.com/levand/immuconf/blob/ca7ec0a4b84936240711016239b3209ef228da70/src/immuconf/config.clj#L111) to replace `~` in filenames specified in `.immuconf.edn` with a value of `(System/getProperty "user.home")` so you might check if that system property points to the same directory where your `~/betfair.edn` file is located.

I have recreated your setup and it works on my machine so it is probably a problem with locations or access rights to your files. Unfortunately, error handling for the no arg invocation of `(immuconf.config/load)` doesn't help in troubleshooting as [it swallows any exceptions and returns `nil`](https://github.com/levand/immuconf/blob/ca7ec0a4b84936240711016239b3209ef228da70/src/immuconf/config.clj#L94). That exception would probably tell you what kind of error occured (some file not found or some IO error happened). You might want to file a pull request with a patch to log such errors as warnings instead of ignoring them.